# Imageview parallax as you scroll

Tags: android

I saw many examples demonstrative parallax background as you scroll or listview parallax but I cannot find a clear example how to implement a parallax effect on images as you scroll in the activity.

An example implementation can be found in Airbnb app. As you scroll down you can see more of the image's bottom and as you scroll up you can see more of the image's top.

Any hints and tips on how to create such effect?

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Searching](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+parallax+tutorial) seems to offer plenty.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are a few libraries that to a parallax effect, it depends on your app if they are useful for your particular case, for example:

- [ParallaxScroll](https://github.com/nirhart/ParallaxScroll)
- [Paralloid](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Paralloid)

Google is your friend pal ;) if none of these suits your needs then you have to create a custom `ScrollView` but that's a longer story, first give them a try and post your results.

### Edit

If none of these fit your requeriments then this is what you have to do:

First, create a custom `ScrollView` so you can listen to scroll changes.

```
public class ObservableScrollView extends ScrollView {

    public interface OnScrollChangedListener {
        public void onScrollChanged(int deltaX, int deltaY);
    }

    private OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener;

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if(mOnScrollChangedListener != null) {
            mOnScrollChangedListener.onScrollChanged(l - oldl, t - oldt);
        }
    }

    public void setOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener listener) {
        mOnScrollChangedListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Obviously you need to use this in your layout instead of the default `ScrollView`:

```
<your.app.package.ObservableScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Also you need to wrap your ImageView inside a container to make the parallax work:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/img_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Finally set your `Activity` as a listener for your brand new `ObservableScrollView` and let the parallax begin:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ObservableScrollView.OnScrollChangedListener {
    private ObservableScrollView mScrollView;
    private View imgContainer;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Init your layout and set your listener
        mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        mScrollView.setOnScrollChangedListener(this);
        // Store the reference of your image container
        imgContainer = findViewById(R.id.img_container);
    }

     @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(int deltaX, int deltaY) {
        int scrollY = mScrollView.getScrollY();
        // Add parallax effect
        imgContainer.setTranslationY(scrollY * 0.5f);
    }
}
```

You can modify the 0.5 value depending on how much parallax you want.

### Edit

The above answer works fine if your ImageView is in the top of the activity. I am posting some code below to add the functionality to have the ImageView anywhere in the activity layout which I successfully made to work. These are generic calculations (might have some mistakes) and with a little tweak you can have it working for your own case.

For this example I have a fix height for the image container 200dp and for the image 240dp. The main purpose is when the image container is in the middle of the screen have no parallax effect and as the user scroll up or down to apply the effect. So as the image container get closer to the top of the screen or closer to the bottom of the screen the more of the parallax effect will be applied. The following calculations are a little hard to understand by reading them so try to make an example with real numbers in paper.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements ObservableScrollView.OnScrollChangedListener {
    private ObservableScrollView mScrollView;
    private View imgContainer;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Init your layout and set your listener
        mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
        mScrollView.setOnScrollChangedListener(this);
        // Store the reference of your image container
        imgContainer = findViewById(R.id.img_container);
        // Store the reference of your image
        mImageView =  findViewById(R.id.img);
    }

     @Override
    public void onScrollChanged(int deltaX, int deltaY) {
        // Get scroll view screen bound
        Rect scrollBounds = new Rect();
        mScrollView.getHitRect(scrollBounds);

        // Check if image container is visible in the screen
        // so to apply the translation only when the container is visible to the user
        if (imgContainer.getLocalVisibleRect(scrollBounds)) {
            Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
            DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
            display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
            // Get screen density
            float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

            // Get screen height in pixels            
            float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
            int screen_height_pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dpHeight, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int half_screen_height = screen_height_pixels/2;

            // Get image container height in pixels
            int container_height_pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 200, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            // Get the location that consider a vertical center for the image (where the translation should be zero)
            int center = half_screen_height - (container_height_pixels/2);

            // get the location (x,y) of the image container in pixels
            int[] loc_screen = {0,0};
            imgContainer.getLocationOnScreen(loc_screen);

            // trying to transform the current image container location into percentage
            // so when the image container is exaclty in the middle of the screen percentage should be zero
            // and as the image container getting closer to the edges of the screen should increase to 100%
            int final_loc = ((loc_screen[1]-center)*100)/half_screen_height;

            // translate the inner image taking consideration also the density of the screen
            mImageView.setTranslationY(-final_loc * 0.4f * density);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it can help someone that is looking for similar functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already saw them but because I cannot see clearly the functionality I am looking for, I decided to ask in case there might be a library out there I missed! But you are right about the part that I have to spend the time and try them first.

Comment: @xinaris did it work? if it did, please accept my post as an answer :)

Comment: thanks for your effort to helping me out! I actually have a similar code for creating the parallax effect for an image I have at the top of the activity which works fine. My question really was for having the parallax effect to an imageview that is anywhere in the scrollview. Your code does not work for that but your guidelines are good. The solution will be similar to your code but to have some mathematics calculating where is the current position of the imageview in the scrollview.

Comment: I added some code to @peguerosdc anwser to get the functionality I asked for. Thanks for your time spending on this.

Comment: @xinaris I've accepted your edit. I'm glad to read that my code was useful.

Comment: Very helpful effort, Thanx dear.

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting null pointer on this line   mScrollView.setOnScrollChangedListener(this);

Comment: @Sumit it seems that `mScrollView` is null, have you initialized it with `findViewById` and are you sure the ID you provided is the correct one?

Comment: Yes , i have initialized it and also the ID provided is correct one.

Comment: thanks a lot for the example, easy to understand and works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

```
   scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged() {
            int top = scrollView.getScrollY(); // Increases when scrolling up ^
            if(top != 0) {
                int newTop = (int) (top * .5f);
                imageFrame.setTop(newTop < 0 ? 0 : newTop);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This makes gap on top of the `ImageView` when moving fast.

Comment: removing the `top != 0` check will fix the gap that shows up on the top when scrolling quickly.

Comment: removing the top != 0, still it makes gap on the top of ImageView when moving fast. Any other solution?