# Scrollview - register listener, when view passed top of scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, nestedscrollview

I need to update my Tabs ([TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)), when user reaches some view in subclassed [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html).

My layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <!-- My Subclassed NestedScrollView. This is due to parallax image on top .-->
    <com.company.recipes.ObservableScrollView>

        <!-- Container for parallax image -->
        <FrameLayout>
            <ImageView/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <!-- Some Content -->
        <View 
           android:id="@+id/divider"/>
        <!-- More Content -->
        <View 
           android:id="@+id/divider2"/>
    </com.company.recipes.ObservableScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
           android:id="@+id/toolbar_detail"
           app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
           android:id="@+id/tab_layout"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

To more clarify what I mean, here is an image with actual data:

[image: Image with data]

TabLayout has 3 fixed tabs. TabLayout always stays on screen. When user scroll down or up, I want to update TabIndicator. This should happen, when it passes Divider.

**So how to make a on scroll listener, which finds out, if view had been scrolled out of visible area?**

Here is my subclassed NestedScrollView: ObservableScrollView.java

```
public class ObservableScrollView extends NestedScrollView {

    public interface OnScrollChangedListener {
        void onScrollChanged(int deltaX, int deltaY);
    }

    private OnScrollChangedListener mOnScrollChangedListener;

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ObservableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);
        if(mOnScrollChangedListener != null) {
            mOnScrollChangedListener.onScrollChanged(l - oldl, t - oldt);
        }
    }

    public void setOnScrollChangedListener(OnScrollChangedListener listener) {
        mOnScrollChangedListener = listener;
    }
}
```

And my onScrollChangedListener which handles parallax image scroll:

```
final ObservableScrollView scrollView = (ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myscrollView);
scrollView.setOnScrollChangedListener(new ObservableScrollView.OnScrollChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onScrollChanged(int deltaX, int deltaY) {
                    int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
                    // Add parallax effect
                    findViewById(R.id.frame_photo).setTranslationY(scrollY * 0.5f);
                }
            });
```

It refers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26990195/imageview-parallax-as-you-scroll) SO question.